# jQuery Ajax promise queue not working when success function fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a single-page app that uses a queuing mechanism based on promise, something like this:

a) a function that handles ajax requests

```
function AjaxSender(SomeAjaxData, FunctionToCallBack, SomeCallBackData) {

   return $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: "POST",
        data: SomeAjaxData,
        success: function (msg, textStatus, request) {

            if (FunctionToCallBack) {

               FunctionToCallBack(SomeCallBackData);
               //problem if there's a bug when this executes
            }
        }
   });
}
```

b) a function that uses a promise object to queue requests

```
var AppAjaxPromise;    
function AjaxRequestQueue(SomeAjaxData, FunctionToCallBack, SomeCallBackData) {

        if (AppAjaxPromise) {

            AppAjaxPromise = AppAjaxPromise.then(function () {

                return AjaxSender(SomeAjaxData, FunctionToCallBack, SomeCallBackData);
            });

            return AppAjaxPromise;
        }

        AppAjaxPromise = AjaxSender(SomeAjaxData, FunctionToCallBack, SomeCallBackData);

        return AppAjaxPromise;
    }
```

When I want to send an ajax request, I call `AjaxRequestQueue(TheAjaxData, TheFunctionToCallBack, TheCallBackData)` and the queuing mechanism ensures that if multiple requests are sent simultaneously, or before one has finished returning, they are queued and processed one after the previous one is done.

The problem occurs when a bug stops the execution of the callback function. If that function bugs, the whole queuing mechanism stops and calling AjaxRequestQueue doesn't trigger ajax requests any more.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Don't mix callback pattern with Promise pattern. Go for one (I would suggest promises), and stick with that all the way through.

Comment: to expand on the previous comment, `$.ajax` returns a promise, so don't use `success` callback, do something like `return $.ajax(-snip-).then(function(msg) { ... });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jQuery's `$.ajax` returns a promise (and since you are using it), abandon the use of the `success` callback. Instead move that code in a `then` callback. This will allow you to chain a `catch` method (jQuery 3.x) call to it to respond to errors. If you don't trigger another error in that `catch` callback, the promise it returns will be resolved again (not rejected), so the rest of your chain will not be aborted:

```
function ajaxSender(someAjaxData, functionToCallBack, someCallBackData) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: "POST",
        data: someAjaxData
    }).then(function (msg, textStatus, request) {
        if (functionToCallBack) {
           functionToCallBack(someCallBackData);
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error occurred, but request queue will not be interrupted', err);
    });
}
```

#### jQuery 2.x

The above needs jQuery 3.x. In jQuery versions before 3.x, you can replace the `catch` method like this (notice the `null` argument):

```
       ...
    }).then(null, function (err) {
       ...
```

...but jQuery 2.x promises are not [Promise/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) compliant, which makes it a pain to get it right. Here is how you could do it for jQuery 2.x. This snippet uses a URL that mimics a delay and an HTTP response status code, which allows it to test request errors, JavaScript run time errors, and sequencing:

```js
function ajaxSender(someAjaxData, functionToCallBack, someCallBackData) {
    return $.ajax({
        // URL for demo: server will use the sleep parameter in the data, 
        //    and will return the given HTTP status
        url: "http://httpstat.us/" + someAjaxData.status, 
        type: "GET", // The demo URL needs a GET
        data: someAjaxData
    }).then(function (data) {
        if (functionToCallBack) {
            try { // Would not be necessary if jQuery 2.x were Promise/A+ compliant
                functionToCallBack(someCallBackData);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(someCallBackData, 'Error occurred during callback');
            }
        }
    }, function (err) { // This second function captures ajax errors
        console.log(someCallBackData, 'HTTP error');
        // Return a resolved promise. 
        // This would not be necessary if jQuery 2.x were Promise/A+ compliant
        return $.when(); 
    }); // In jQuery 3.x you would chain a catch call here instead of the try/catch.
}

var appAjaxPromise = $.when();    
function ajaxRequestQueue(someAjaxData, functionToCallBack, someCallBackData) {
    appAjaxPromise = appAjaxPromise.then(function () {
        return ajaxSender(someAjaxData, functionToCallBack, someCallBackData);
    });
    return appAjaxPromise;
}

// Demo: the ajax data argument is also used to define the HTTP response status and  
//   the sleep time, and the data argument identifies the number of the call

// Survive an HTTP error
ajaxRequestQueue({ status: 404, sleep: 1000 }, myCallBack, 1); 
// Survive a runtime error in the callback
ajaxRequestQueue({ status: 200, sleep: 2000 }, myErrorGeneratingCallBack, 2); 
// Demo that the callback calls remain in the right order
ajaxRequestQueue({ status: 200, sleep: 3000 }, myCallBack, 3); 
ajaxRequestQueue({ status: 200, sleep: 2000 }, myCallBack, 4);
ajaxRequestQueue({ status: 200, sleep: 1000 }, myCallBack, 5); 

function myCallBack(data) {
    console.log(data, "My callback is called");
}
function myErrorGeneratingCallBack(data) {
    console.log(data, "My callback is called");
    throw "I threw an error in my callback";
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can still continue the above pattern when moving to jQuery 3: it will still work. But ideally, you should then migrate the code to the `catch`-based version that I provided at the top.

#### Some other remarks

There is a consensus to only capitalise the first letter of a variable when it is a constructor/class.

By initialising `appAjaxPromise` as an immediately resolved promise, you can avoid code repetition:

```
var appAjaxPromise = $.when();    
function ajaxRequestQueue(someAjaxData, functionToCallBack, someCallBackData) {
    appAjaxPromise = appAjaxPromise.then(function () {
        return ajaxSender(someAjaxData, functionToCallBack, someCallBackData);
    });
    return appAjaxPromise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I will test it later today and will let you know. In the first code block, will the .catch execute when a) there's an ajax error and/or b) the ajax request worked ok but there's an error in the execution of the callback function following a success on the ajax?

Comment: Yes, in both cases the `catch` callback will be called.

Comment: I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).then(...).catch is not a function However, if I remove the .catch(...) portion it works.

Comment: Which version of jQuery? If 1.x or 2.x, use `.then(null, function (err)` instead of `.catch(function (err)`.

Comment: Problem is that this doesn't queue resquests. I call 3 test requests from the client and on the server I put the thread to sleep for different times based on the paramater, with the first request sleeping 15 sec, the second for 10 sec the third returning after 5 seconds. So the second request shouldn't fire until the first is returned but that's not the console output I get.

Comment: Which version of jQuery? Can you use 3.x or not?

Comment: Must use jQuery 2

Comment: OK, I added a snippet that works with jQuery 2. It needed a bit of tweeking because promises in jQuery 2.x do not function according to the standards. The snippet shows that the sequencing is in the right order, and that errors in either the ajax call or in the callback are not stopping the sequence.

Comment: This is really high quality code! It works like a charm, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer will fix it, but the callbacks you are using in the success function might not be accessible from there.

You can add extra data to the request like so... and it will be accessible with  'this....'. (see success).

Not sure if you should ether :p I have been doing this to pass data from inside an object without having to change the ajax' context or using $.proxy. Also I have been able to access an object's function that fires a request, from inside that request's success, making it recursive for sending files in chunks.

If there are any comments on doing this, I would love to hear.

```
return $.ajax({
    FunctionToCallBack: FunctionToCallBack,
    SomeCallBackData: SomeCallBackData,

    url: ...,
    type: "POST",
    data: SomeAjaxData,
    success: function (msg, textStatus, request) {

        if (this.FunctionToCallBack) {

           this.FunctionToCallBack(this.SomeCallBackData);
           //problem if there's a bug when this executes
        }
    }
```

});